# php links in a table based on sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am populating a table using php from an array (populated by an mysql query). The table code I am using is:

```
     <thead>
            <tr>
        <hr>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Nick Name</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
            <th>Active</th>
            <th>Admin</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>

<?php
        foreach ($portfolio as $row)    
        {   
            echo("<tr>");
            echo("<td>" . $row["username"] . "</td>");
            echo("<td>" . $row["nickname"] . "</td>");
            echo("<td>" . $row["role"] . "</td>");
            echo("<td>" . $row["unit"] . "</td>");
            echo("<td>" . $row["active"] . "</td>");
            echo("<td>" . $row["isadmin"] . "</td>");
            echo("</tr>");
        }
?>
```

I have been trying without luck to find a way to have the first column in the table a hyperlink that allows editing of that users details (IE redirects to another page/php).  The array itself is being populated using this code:

```
   //now lets get the user's stock info
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        $stock = lookup($row["username"]);
        $stock["username"] = $row["username"];
        $stock["nickname"] = $row["nickname"];
        $stock["role"] = $row["role"];
        $stock["unit"] = $row["unit"];
        $stock["active"] = $row["active"];

    $portfolio[] = $stock;   
    }
```

How can I make the results of the sql query / php a link within the table?

Thanks for the help, I am new to php/mysql and trying to find my feet;

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do something like the following, then on your user edit page you can get the username with `$_GET['user']`

```
<?php
        foreach ($portfolio as $row)    
        {   

            echo("<td><a href='user-edit.php?user=" . $row["username"] . "'>" . $row["username"] . "</a></td>");

        }
?>
```

Given an unique username ofc, else you can do it with the id or any unique field.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail around how I should use the $_GET['user'] please?

Comment: Well you just need to use it in a SQL query (SELECT * WHERE username=) to get the user. Do note that you'll have to format it for security reason (see SQL Injections)

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried as you described above but forgot to actually update the file on my apache server (doh!).  Thanks for the help.  Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use $portfolio variable ? It just stock the data you already have in $rows.

Then, just use this :

```
echo '<td>
         <a href="your_script.php?user='. $row['id'] .'">'. $row["username"] .'</a> 
      </td>';
```

I think you have an user ID in your table ?

Comment: I do have a user id in the table.  I am using the portfolio vairable so I can change some of the data from the database to a more human readable format when displayed (example isadmin is 1 or 0 in the database but is displayed as YES or NO for ease).  I am just giving the solutions a try now.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing this line

```
echo("<td>" . $row["username"] . "</td>");
```

to this

```
echo("<td><a href="???">" . $row["username"] . "</a></td>");
```

will make the first column clickable.  Of course you'll need to fill in the target of the link.  Making the details editable is a lot more code though.